# Tensorflow in Rust, unresolved import

Tags: tensorflow, rust, importerror

I am trying to use tensorflow in rust. I have followed the instructions on the [github page](https://github.com/tensorflow/rust#getting-started) of the rust tensorflow project. My `Cargo.toml` file has

```
[dependencies]
tensorflow = "0.15.0"
```

in it. My processor is an Intel i7-8700 and I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, which ought to mean they download a prebuilt binary, as per the github page, and I don't need to worry about other prerequisites.

I `cargo run`, and cargo downloads and builds a lot of packages. Then I try to copy their `xor.rs` example. It starts with a bunch of imports. First a lot of `use std::` which are fine. Then we get to the tensorflow imports, starting with

```
use tensorflow::ops;
use tensorflow::train::AdadeltaOptimizer;
use tensorflow::train::MinimizeOptions;
use tensorflow::train::Optimizer;
```

and I immediately run into import issues. Here is the top of the list:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `tensorflow::ops`
 --> src/main.rs:7:5
  |
7 | use tensorflow::ops;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `ops` in the root

error[E0432]: unresolved import `tensorflow::train`
 --> src/main.rs:8:17
  |
8 | use tensorflow::train::AdadeltaOptimizer;
  |                 ^^^^^ could not find `train` in `tensorflow`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `tensorflow::train`
 --> src/main.rs:9:17
  |
9 | use tensorflow::train::MinimizeOptions;
  |                 ^^^^^ could not find `train` in `tensorflow`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `tensorflow::train`
  --> src/main.rs:10:17
   |
10 | use tensorflow::train::Optimizer;
   |                 ^^^^^ could not find `train` in `tensorflow`
```

But according to both tensorflow's `src/lib.rs` file in the github repository linked above, and the [documentation](https://tensorflow.github.io/rust/tensorflow/index.html), there really should be modules `tensorflow::ops` and `tensorflow::train` available.

How come my cargo can't find them?

Comment: [“This module currently requires the experimental_training feature.”](https://tensorflow.github.io/rust/tensorflow/ops/index.html)

Comment: @mcarton Well, that was a simple fix. Now there are lots of other problems, like `expected struct "tensorflow::graph::Output", found struct "tensorflow::graph::Operation"` all over, but those aren't as mysterious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved in the comments. I had to edit the `Cargo.toml` file to read

```
tensorflow = {version = "0.15.0", features = ["experimental_training"]}
```

as `experimental training` is apparently a required feature for these modules.

Comment: The remaining errors, many of which were `expected struct "tensorflow::graph::Output", found struct "tensorflow::graph::Operation"`, were all fixed with suitable calls to `into()` and `from()`.